# SQLCipher for Android support for MIPS

Tags: android, sqlcipher

Is there a MIPS port/binaries available for SQLCipher for Android? I could only find the libs (.so) for x86 and ARM. We are working on an android application that requires database encryption and targeted towards MIPS based devices among others. Any pointers on how I can get hold of MIPS specific binaries?

Answer (score -1):

MIPS is not one of the supported SQLCipher for Android architectures. You could try building from source, and adjusting the build chain to build for that architecture. If you're interested in a commercially supported custom build, reach out to the core SQLCipher team at http://zetetic.net/contact.